# Core Data model for test-taking iOS app

Tags: objective-c, database, ios, core-data

I'm building an iOS app for test-taking and I want to be sure of my model before proceeding.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540885/db-design-survey-quiz-with-questions-and-answers) very helpful and tried to implement a simplified version for Core Data.

Here are some of my assumptions:

- Each `User` can take multiple tests
- Each `User` has one set of answers per `Test` taken
- Each `Test` has one `User`
- Each `Question` has many answers

Here is my Core Data model:

[image]

Overall, what do you think of my database schema? Is it sufficient to handle a simple test-taking app?

- Also, are `Test_Questions` and `User_Answers` necessary?

  - I could, in theory, have a relationship directly between `Test` and`Question`? `Test -->> Question.` I would like to know which is better.

Here are my model headers for `Test_Questions` and `User_Answers`:

### Test_Questions.h

```
@class Question, Test;

@interface Test_Questions : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) Test *test;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *questions;
@end

@interface Test_Questions (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addQuestionsObject:(Question *)value;
- (void)removeQuestionsObject:(Question *)value;
- (void)addQuestions:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeQuestions:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

### User_Answers.h

```
@class Answer, User;

@interface User_Answers : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) User *user;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *userAnswersSet;
@end

@interface User_Answers (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addUserAnswersSetObject:(Answer *)value;
- (void)removeUserAnswersSetObject:(Answer *)value;
- (void)addUserAnswersSet:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeUserAnswersSet:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

`Test_Questions` and `User_Answers` are not necessary since they do not hold any attribution and are one-to-one relationships with `Test` and `User`, respectively. It is always suspect when you have a plural table name.

However, the model fails to support the ability of a `User` to take multiple `Test`s. To fix that, `User.testTaken` should be replaced by `User.testsTaken` and made into a one-to-many relationship with Test.

Also, it seems a bit odd that a `Test` can only be taken by a single `User`, but if that's your requirement, then so be it.